# Shell command to loop over names of output file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a C code and I use it to extract file and write in to separate files such as exax0.txt, ..., exax202.txt. To do that I use

```
for i in $(seq 0 202); 
do echo $i | ./f.out exa-NO-hyp.bin exax${i}.txt <<< "${i}"
done
```

Instead, I would like to have my output files named as exax495.txt, exax535.txt, ..., exax8545.txt. To do so, I tried something like:

```
for i in $(seq 0 202); 
do echo $i | ./f.out exa-NO-hyp.bin exax${(i*40+495)}.txt <<< "${i}"  
done
```

But it says, `-bash: exax${i*40}.txt: bad substitution`

Can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: Note that `echo "$i" | program ... <<< "$i"` is wasting the pipe.  The input ends up coming from the here string.  Drop the `echo "$i" |` part.

Comment: No harm to spend an extra line of code: something like filenumber=xxx and `./f.out exa-no-hyp.bin exa${filenumber}.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$((...))` to perform arithmetic.

I.e. a simple use would be:

```
for i in {1..10}; do touch file$(($i+5)).txt ; done
```

Or in your case:

```
for i in $(seq 0 202); do echo $i | ./f.out exa-NO-hyp.bin exax$(($i*40+495)).txt <<< "${i}"; done
```

### See also:

- [Arithmetic Expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html) in the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html).
- [Arithmetic Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) in the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)

Comment: `$` is not necessary on variables in `$((...))` blocks. and a reference to the  [Arithemetic Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) section of the bash reference manual is likely a better than a reference to the (often poor) TLDP ABS guide.